# Can you have an MBR partition and a GPT partition on the same RAID 5 VHD in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, partition, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have a Power Edge T610 with a PERC 6 RAID 5 Array, recently i posted a question about expanding the array with other drives and was able to use OMSA to add additional drives to the array and then had to use a third party partitioning tool to expand the partition on the C drive since that the drive i was running out of space on -

So on the Power Edge I have 2 partitions on a single VHD controlled by PERC 6

Both partitions are MBR limiting me to 2 TB - YUCK!

Can i leave the C Drive partition as MBR and change the format of the F drive aka my data drive to GPT so i can utilize more space than the 2 TB limit? would i do this in windows server 2008 R2?

IF i can do this - is it a smart move or a bad move? I don't want to risk any instability on the machine at all so if doing this poses some kind of risk I'd rather not do it for now.

Thank you !